# Making XMODIFIERS=@im=none emacs24 standard

Tags: shell, emacs

I run emacs as `XMODIFIERS=@im=none emacs24`, otherwise some multi-keys for typing things like à won't work.

How can I make this option permanent, so when I type `emacs24`, it runs as `XMODIFIERS=@im=none emacs24`.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an alias for it. Add this line to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`):

```
alias emacs24='XMODIFIERS=@im=none emacs24'
```

Then, launching `emacs24` will actually run `XMODIFIERS=@im=none emacs24`.